# How to apply MySQL 'LIKE' to a column which is specified in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I need to combine 2 columns and find whether the combined content matches something. However the following query doesn't work:

```
select 
  concat(column1,column2) as combined_column 
from 
  my_table 
where 
  combined_column like '%value%';
```

MySQL reports an error that 'combined_column' doesn't exist. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace your where clausole with this one:

```
where concat(column1,column2) like '%value%';
```

**Explanation**: The where clausole isn't able to read the var named in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  concat(column1,column2) as combined_column 
from 
  my_table 
where 
  Concat(column1,column2) like '%value%';
```